# Multiple Select Queries vs Select Multiple Variables in a Single Query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT A,B,C,D from Table1 Where Constraint1
```

vs

```
SELECT A from Table1 Where Constraint1
SELECT B from Table1 Where Constraint1
SELECT C from Table1 Where Constraint1
SELECT D from Table1 Where Constraint1
```

Is there any performance difference ?

Comment: There's a fundamental semantic difference or did you mean to change the 'A' to 'B', 'C' & 'D'?

Comment: It was a typo and thanks Robert for correcting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the first one is faster, but.. let's test it!

Considering in the second group of selects to return A, B, C & D.

IN `SQL SERVER 2008 R2`:

Let's try it:

```
Create Table Test 
(
A int not null,
B int not null,
C int not null,
D int not null,
)

insert into Test values (1,2,3,5)
```

Running Execution plan for the first:

```
select A, B, C, D from Test
```

and this results on:

[image]

It's on spanish, but you can see the numbers. Has a CPU Cost of `0.0000796`

So, let's try it with the second:

```
select A from Test
select B from Test
select C from Test
select D from Test
```

and this results on:

[image]

As you can see, each select use the same CPU Cost, but.. here has to do 4 selects. With a little row, you won't see the difference, but, let me update, with more data

**UPDATE**

Now, I made a couple of inserts, and now we have:

```
select count(*) from test

76183 rows
```

Let's do the same: We got the first `select`, and in the execution plan, we got:

[image]

as you can see, we got more `CPU COST` (of course, more rows!)

And then let's check the 4 selects:

[image]

Again, we got the same `CPU COST`, but we run it 4 times !!

In conclusion, there is no difference on showing one field or four, but we got a big difference on doing one `select` against 4.

I know it's a simply question, but I wanted to do some "science/research"

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference - the first method only have to scan the table once, while the second has to scan the table 4 times.

While it is possible for a SQL provider to optimize this, I doubt any of them does, and Anyways, SQL is usually activated from an host language, and each query is sent separately to the provider - so there is no way for the provider to optimize separate queries together...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a typo in your second case,the first one would be quicker as you are only performing a single query and hence only making one connection.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you want to retrieve A four times.

In the 1st option, only 1 query is made and in the 2nd you have 4 which means the DB will have to execute the query multiple times.

The 1st option should always be faster unless you have a very large table and a full table scan is needed to return all the 4 columns. In that case, there is a small chance that if A was indexed the combined result of the 4 round-trips could be faster than getting all the columns.

If there was a typo in your 2nd option, then 1. should always be faster.